# Why "babel-node" spins 2 processes?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I have the following script in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "babel-node app"
}
```

When I run `npm start` and then `ps aux | grep node`, I see 2 processes running:

```
mishamoroshko   18102  58.9  4.2  3173444 174656 s001  S+    2:37pm   0:03.18 node /Users/mishamoroshko/my-project/node_modules/babel/bin/_babel-node app
mishamoroshko   18101   0.0  0.4  3045884  15488 s001  S+    2:37pm   0:00.08 node /Users/mishamoroshko/my-project/node_modules/.bin/babel-node app
```

Which one is my app, and why is it run in 2 processes?

Comment: Have you tried to kill one of the processes and see if your app is still up and running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`babel-node` is the root process, and it spawns `_babel-node` which is the process that is actually executing your application.

By default, Babel spawns a child Node process after processing arguments passed to a subprocess, but the parent process stays alive (which is what you are seeing). You can see that logic [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/ffbf5b0b47ae820fd9f33eb300a889537de4ddb8/packages/babel-cli/bin/babel-node).

Looking at that file, one option supported by Babel is that you can install `kexec` alongside Babel, which it will attempt to use before falling back to spawning a child process. If `kexec` is installed, the entire parent Node process will be replaced by the child, so you'll only have one process in your list.

So if you want this behavior to stop, just add `kexec` to your `package.json` along side `babel`.